# Denormalize Array<A> and Array<B> where clause is true, set B as named property on A

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to 'denormalize' two arrays (IObservableArray and IObservableArray) where array A has objects with id's that point to id's of objects in array B. I would like to put objects from array B that match the id of the object in array A on object A as a dynamically named property. The arrays are `IObservableArray`s from `mobx` but that should not be of importance.

I'm trying to achieve this:

```
var aArr: IObservableArray<A extends { bId: number }>;
var bArr: IObservableArray<B extends { id: number }>;

var d = denormalize(aArr, bArr, (a, b) => a.bId === b.id, "b");
console.log(d[0].b) // => B
```

I tried the following:

```js
export function denormalize<A, B, K extends string, TRet extends A & {[asProperty: K]: B}>(
    arr1: IObservableArray<A>,
    arr2: IObservableArray<B>,
    where: (a: A, b: B) => boolean,
    asProperty: K
): IObservableArray<TRet> {
    return observable.array(); // stub
}
```

But it says `[ts] An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.
(parameter) k: K extends string`

Is there a way to make the `A[asProperty]: B` work so that the compiler knows that the type returned by `denormalize` has an additional property with name `asProperty` and it autocompletes as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a generic type in the index signature, the indexer parameter must be `string` or `number` (this is according to the [spec](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.9.4)).

What you can do is use the mapped type syntax (`[Prop in Key] : Type`)

```
export function denormalize<A, B, K extends string, TRet extends A & { [P in K]: B}>(
    arr1: IObservableArray<A>,
    arr2: IObservableArray<B>,
    where: (a: A, b: B) => boolean,
    asProperty: K
): IObservableArray<TRet> {
    // ...
}
```

Will work :

```
console.log(d[0].b) // => B
```

**Edit**

As @jcalz mentioned in the comments, the signature can also use the `Record<K extends string, T>` type which is the same as `{ [P in K]: B}>`. Using this the signature would be :

```
export function denormalize<A, B, K extends string, TRet extends A &  Record<K,B>>(
    arr1: IObservableArray<A>,
    arr2: IObservableArray<B>,
    where: (a: A, b: B) => boolean,
    asProperty: K
): IObservableArray<TRet>
```

Comment: Maybe mention using `Record<K, B>` from the [TypeScript standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v2.6.2/lib/lib.d.ts#L1338) ?

Comment: @jcalz Yes you are right, that would be equivalent, will add